# How to loop over a file containing a list of directories and execute a command in each with python

Tags: python

I have multiple subdirectories and text file (test.txt) that includes the names of those subdirectories in a main directory. My code should read the name of each directory from test.txt file in main directory and run "gmx mdrun ..." program in each subdirectory. How can I achieve that? My code and test.txt are as the following. My code gives the below error. In addition to that error, I think my code doesn't get the name of each subdirectory?

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./read.py", line 11, in
>   
>       os.chdir(path/line) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

**test.txt:**

> metan-1
>
> ethanol
>
> 1-2-benzene
>
> ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
path=os.getcwd()


with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
        array.append(line)
os.chdir(path/line)
os.system("gmx mdrun -v -deffnm md")
os.chdir('..')

f.close()
```

Comment: You realize that whitespace and indentation is important to how python scripts are interpreted and run right?

Comment: your question is inappropriate, remove that spacing at the beginning of `os.system("gmx mdrun -v -deffnm md")`

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error says: that indent is unexpected.  Don't put that whitespace before `os.system(...)`

Comment: I removed the whitespace before os.system but I get this error  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./read.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.chdir('path/line')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/line'
`

Comment: `os.chdir(path/line)` should be `os.chdir(path + "/" + line)`

Comment: @erhan Edits aren't supposed to change the essence of questions, which seems to be what's going on here. When the question's essence changes, any answers which were pertinent to the original question become displaced, and potential learning for others is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but you're looking for something more like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
path=os.getcwd()

COMMAND='gmx mdrun -v -deffnm md'

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        os.chdir(line.strip())
        os.system(COMMAND)
        os.chdir('..')
```

The notable changes are:

- moving the `os.system` execution within the loop over the input file, so that using an array as a buffer is unnecessary
- using `.strip` on the line to remove newline characters
- (optional) setting the command to a constant, ***COMMAND***
- the f.close() is unnecessary since files opened with the with statement are implicitly closed.

EDIT:

Addressing the error, since *path/line* is relative, `os.chdir` will attempt to move into a directory relative to where the script is executed, same place that (the also relatively accessed) *test.txt* exists.

EDIT:

For completeness, I would have written this script as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import os
import sys
from subprocess import call


COMMAND='gmx mdrun -v -deffnm md'
DIRECTORY_FILE='test.txt'

def main(directory_file=DIRECTORY_FILE, command=COMMAND):
    with directory_file:
        for line in directory_file:
            os.chdir(line.strip())
            call(command.split())
            os.chdir(os.pardir)

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Execute commands on a list of directories.')
    parser.add_argument('--command',
                        '-c',
                        type=str,
                        default=COMMAND,
                        help='the command to be run')
    parser.add_argument('--directory-file',
                        type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                        default=DIRECTORY_FILE,
                        help='a file containing a list of directories to run the command on')

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    main(args.directory_file, args.command)
```

It's reusable, its use documented, and it's not hardcoded for a specific use case.

Comment: the safe/appropriate way of using this is using subprocessing.Popen, not os.system

Comment: I'm aware of that, but didn't want to change the OP's code too drastically.

Comment: as bschlueter says, we aim to help, if we added every personal optimisations we each use to answers for people that don't neceseraly have a deep understanding of the subject we would just create an environment were newbies would never want to ask questions, and answers would have a too strong a basis on opinion

Comment: @bschlueter Your code works but it need a small editing which I couldn't do it. The program runs in all directories at the same time. As a matter of fact it should run in each directory respectively. For instance, the program should start to run for second subdirectory after the calculation of the first subdirectory is completed. As for the third subdirectory , the program should start to run after the second completed and so on. Can you please edit the code?

Comment: The original version runs serially for me, as does the second one, though I tested that fact by setting the command to a script containing `sleep 3`, which indicates that the problem is with the `gmx mdrun -v -deffnm md` program, or potentially, your OS. Which begs the questions, what is `gmx` and which OS are you on? I've seen programs which background themselves immediately after execution, such as the Oracle DB installer, and there are workarounds for that, but they're rather involved.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, Python does what you tell it to do, not what you want it to do.

```
os.chdir(path/line)
```

This line is telling Python:

- I have a string called path
- I have a string called line
- I divide path by line

This is not what you WANT to do, but it is what you have written. Therefore you just have to use a simple concatenation, the slash symbol on its own is divide, with the slash inside quote marks. Like so:

```
os.chdir(path + "/" + line)
```

That should solve it.

**BUT** you have read line from a file, which means it will probably (see ALLWAYS) contain an end of line character therefore:

```
os.chdir(path + "/" + line[:-1]) # So all chars in line except for last
```

If you are wondering why this is, it is simple, chdir requires a path in string format, therefore you have to add the strings you have to form the full path. Notice the use of ADDING to explain this, it is important that you understand that that is exactly what you are doing, adding strings to get a new one.

Comment: I tried what you suggested `os.chdir(path + "/" + line)` but the code gave this error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/Desktop/work/metan-1\n'`.  Your command  added "\n" to the end of directory patwhay as you see from the error.

Comment: no, the "\n" character is at the end of every line read from input of a file, you are meant to remove it, I didn't think to state that my bad

Comment: so you can just write: `os.chdir(path + "/" + line[:-1])`